# Using Autolayout changes button position

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I made a view without using auto layout . The buttons positions was same as that in .xib file when I run the app on device . But when I used autolayout option one of my button is stick to the bottom (Although having right position in .xib file) . What constraints should I use to adjust that button on same position . I am a beginner please help .

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) may help you get to basic understanding of autolayout. Autolayout is tricky feature, get a better understanding, other wise it may cause you real troubles!!

Comment: you need to include screenshots and code

Answer (score 0):

In the Interface Builder, you should be able to command-alt-= to update the view frames to match your constraints. That should make the problem obvious.

Answer (score 0):

update your constraint from that button. 
remove constraint Bottom space to superview and make constraint as you want your button upper side.

Answer (score 0):

you can press "command A" to select all items on the nib file and then go editor->Resolve Auto Layout Issues->Reset to suggested constraints